# Why to use BitmapFactory.Options.inTempStorage?

Tags: java, android, image, performance, memory

What are intended use cases for the `BitmapFactory.Options.inTempStorage` option?

[Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inTempStorage) is pretty terse on this:

> Temp storage to use for decoding. Suggest 16K or so.

If I'm not mistaken it means that if you don't provide the buffer explicitly, it would create and use one by itself.

So the only benefit I see is reusing the same 16K buffer for multiple decodings which seems to have quite questionable impact on performance/memory usage optimization.

So **why SDK authors give us control over the temp storage for decoding?** Should providing much greater buffer improve decoding performance?

Can someone expand on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your assumption is the correct one - this option is mainly for recycling the buffer itself.

From the Android [Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.java):

```
// pass some temp storage down to the native code. 1024 is made up,
// but should be large enough to avoid too many small calls back
// into is.read(...) This number is not related to the value passed
// to mark(...) above.
byte [] tempStorage = null;
if (opts != null) tempStorage = opts.inTempStorage;
if (tempStorage == null) tempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
```

This means that if you do not send this buffer, it will be allocated. Though does not look like an optimization for most cases, if you load many small images  - the allocation of a 16K buffer per image might be pricy.

Regarding the buffer size, as you can see from the comments in the code - there is no magic number. What happens is that the Native code that decodes the image, uses the InputStream managed code to fetch the actual raw bytes (from disk/network etc). It uses the allocated buffer to communicate the bytes for each READ call. So, it is really depends on the InputStream. For example, disk IS might read from the disk in a bulk of 4k and then 16k is more than enough - passing in a buffer bigger than that will not improve the performance since the buffer will not fill up more than 4k at each READ call.

In any case, considering this kind of optimization should be for a really specific cases - if you have such a case, you can provide a bigger buffer and see if it has any affect on the performance.